# Send uart commands through bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, uart

I bought a raspberry pi 3. I ordered the Move controller it's a Kickstarter project.

They use the phone to send uart commands through Bluetooth and they put a Dev documentation online.

What I fail to understand is if it's possible to send the uart commands through the raspberry pi's Bluetooth ? Is this possible ? And can someone give a simple explanation how that would work ?

Comment: There's not really any such thing as "UART commands", there's just information serialized for UART, which amounts information serialized for just about anything because UART has very little structure (there is a bit of a catch with start/stop bits and parity, but it is not much of one), so yes, but obviously you'd need a bluetooth receiver on the other end.  If the "Move controller" includes this, I'm not sure why you are asking about UART.  If it doesn't, give up on this idea now.

Comment: @goldilocks yes it has a Bluetooth receiver because it works also through a phone app. So what I want to do is send commands from raspb to this receiver.

Comment: Okay, and the Pi 3 is bluetooth too.  So your question is really about bluetooth and *what* to do with UART?

Comment: @goldilocks yes. I want to create a webui or a simple API to talk to it. It would be best if I could use something like nodejs. But I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: You should probably remove all references to UART from this then, I think.   It's going to confuse and distract -- I'm sure there are plenty of people out there who know how to use the bluetooth but not the UART, just as there are vice versa (myself included).

Comment: Struggling with the same issue with Move, put in a request with Move support. Perhaps they can shed some light on things.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the direction of using hcitool cmd combined with the UART command overview provided by Teptron: http://www.teptron.com/MOVE_UART_Commands_ver1.0.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Move developers page](http://www.teptron.com/developers.html),

> In the UART API documents you will find all commands that will be possible to send through the micro USB connector on MOVE.

It looks like you should be able to connect the MOVE to a Raspberry Pi via a USB-A to micro USB cable. It will show up as a USB-to-serial device in `/dev`. Run the following command to get a list of possible devices:

```
$ ls -hl /dev/ttyU* /dev/ttyA*
```